# Web Service worker notification click - open url on same page

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have a web worker that i added 'notificationclick' event.
I want to navigate to url in the same tab and not open a new tab.

any clue how to do this?

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    const id = event.notification.data.id;
    let path = 'http://' + event.target.location.host;
    if (event.notification.data.type === 'invite') 
        path += '/invite/' + id;
    else 
        path += '/notification/' + id;
    event.notification.close();
    const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window',
        includeUncontrolled: true
    })
        .then((windowClients) => {
            let matchingClient = null;
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                if (windowClient.url === path) {
                    matchingClient = windowClient;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (matchingClient) {
                return matchingClient.focus();
            } else {
                return clients.openWindow(path);
            }
        });

    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Nope. There is nothing in the internet about it :(